# Sending socket from Listener Service to Worker Service in a Server program in Android

Tags: java, android, sockets, client-server

I am new to android programming. I writing a client server program. I want to create `ServerService` which listen for incoming connections, once request comes from the client it creates two other services `SendService` and `ReceiveService` to write and read from the socket in two different threads. Hence I derived these services from `IntentService`. How to pass socket information to `SendService` and `ReceiveService`? Can I have a simple member variable in these two services and set it from `ServerService`? If so how to set this value? Using `getBaseContext()`?

Answer (score 0):

A service is just a class that extends Service, you can have the same tool set as any class. So your answer is yes, and you assign it via your preferred method.

Comment: My confusion is mainly due to the fact that we dont create the Service instance explicitly. Can I tell the system to populate this slot while creating an instance?

Comment: Services are basically activities with no UI. You start a service via intent just like activities and you can either have them do things on their own, or bind them to give you more direct access (for things like media players)

Comment: Yes. But specifically how to I send the socket information from ServerService to SendService? Are services completely wrong choice in this scenario?

Comment: Not the wrong choice, how is it obtaining the socket information?